# Synchronize the schedule of tow Jobs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in sqlserver, that contain the start and End schedule of execution of a job-1 in Database-1.

I have another DataBase-2, I should create a new Job-2 to start when Job-1 finish execution.

So I should write a script to test the tow schedule:

```
 EndTime(Job-1) > StartTime(Job-2)
```

Someone please can suggest me a solution, How can I start the script because the first time I'll do it knowing that I'm beginner in sqlServer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, let me just get my glass ball to look into your problem.

Comment: Also, are you creating jobs in Db2 or they are already there and you need to test if they start after the one from Db1 finishes. How do you know which job in Db2 has to start after which in Db1? Do you have link table or some sort of ordering or?

Comment: I have the access on table in DB1 that contain [START_DATE],
[END_DATE]. I'll create a job in DB2 to execute just when Job 1 finishes.

Comment: Why not just put both items in the same agent job as two different job steps, and put a USE command at the top of the second script to point to the new DB when the first job step finishes?